# Can't get string from spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have spinner that have 5 text string. I want to get a string from the spinner, but I only get the first string (i can't get the second, third.....).

i use this syntax(below) but still failed:

```
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerItem);
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
          this, R.array.SpinnerArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

  String SpinnerText = myspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: spinner can only select one thing a time.

Comment: Spinners are single-value selectors. Did you try `adapter.getItem(index)` yet?

Comment: i want to get the second string but when i click it i can't get this string (second string) otherwise i get the first string

Comment: [Check out this blog](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517)

Answer (score 3):

By using onItemSelectedLIstener() method you can get each spinner value into string.

Main.java

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
      int arg2, long arg3) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String selection=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected" + selection, 30).show();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the selected item from the spinner first you need to set the listener for spinner using

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and u need to implement the interface OnItemSelectedListener
and finally override the methods

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
selection.setText(items[position]);
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
selection.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
in onclick listener of spinner use this code to get String of selected item

```
 String s = spinneradapter.getItemAtPosition(Integer.parseInt(position));
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
String mySpinner = spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.getItemAtPosition(0).toString()//First string
spinner.getItemAtPosition(1).toString()//second string
spinner.getItemAtPosition(2).toString()//third string
```

Answer (score 0):

see below code it may help you.

```
    spin_search.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int id,
                        long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(Sms_logs.this, "you select : " + adapter.getItem(id), 2000).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```